# Loop through all names and id and store data in the datafram after requesting through discord api

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, while-loop

I want to loop through the channel ids and corresponding names and store the data in a data frame, it can only store 25 per id, so if I have 3 IDs, the total should be 75. The issue is when i use the code i have shown here, it only stores the first id and name in the list, and not all of if, this is the code,

```
collection_name=['A','B','C']
channel_id =['880281356335206440','899531896571187210','293431696871187210']  
while True:
    for c,i in zip(set(collection_name),set(channel_id)):              
        r=requests.get(f'https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/{i}/messages/search?content=buy', headers=headers)
        json_texts = json.loads(r.text)
        id = []
        type = []
        content = []
        channel_id = []
        attachments = []
        embeds = []
        mention_roles = []
        pinned = []
        mention_everyone = []
        tts = []
        timestamp = []
        edited_timestamp = []
        flags = []
        components = []
        author =[]
        mentions = []
        searches = []
        for i in json_texts['messages']:
            id.append(i[0]['id'])
            type.append(i[0]['type'])
            content.append(i[0]['content'])
            channel_id.append(i[0]['channel_id'])
            attachments.append(i[0]['attachments'])
            embeds.append(i[0]['embeds'])
            mention_roles.append(i[0]['mention_roles'])
            pinned.append(i[0]['pinned'])
            mention_everyone.append(i[0]['mention_everyone'])
            tts.append(i[0]['tts'])
            timestamp.append(i[0]['timestamp'])
            edited_timestamp.append(i[0]['edited_timestamp'])
            flags.append(i[0]['flags'])
            components.append(i[0]['components'])
            author.append(i[0]['author'])
            mentions.append(i[0]['mentions'])
            time.sleep(0.01)
        discord_dict = {'id':id,'type':type,'content':content,'channel_id':channel_id,'attachments':attachments,'embeds':embeds,
                            'mention_roles':mention_roles,'pinned':pinned,'mention_everyone':mention_everyone,'tts':tts,'timestamp':timestamp,
                            'edited_timestamp':edited_timestamp,'flags':flags,'components':components,'author':author,
                            'mentions':mentions,'collectionName':c}
    dic=pd.DataFrame(discord_dict)    
    dic.to_csv(f'{c}'+'_buy'+'.csv')
    pass
    break
    dic.head()
```

So I need someone to show me how to modify the code to store all 3 ids and names in the data, so I have 75 in total with the columns of id and names included, this would be used to store over 1000 names and ids, but the modification i receive here, should work for all,

Comment: please edit your question by reformating your code part

Comment: I don't know how to do that here on StackOverflow